# How do I print the 'cnt' variable from the second method in the 'main' method?

Tags: java, variables, methods

[I want to print the returned 'cnt' varible in the 'main' method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5wxR.png)

Comment: Are you joking?

Comment: What have you tried? In the time it took you to create that bitmap you could have Googled the answer and solved your problem yourself.

Comment: You actually removed the question after getting the solution? Just when I thought this post couldn't get any worse. Questions are kept here to help others in the future. Granted, your question wouldn't have helped many people but it's still quite selfish to remove it.

Comment: You cannot deface your post here by removing content. If you want to delete it, do so by using the link below the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function from your `main`, then use `System.out.println()`:

The `moveDisks` method requires that you invoke it with an `int` and four `String`s. After you call it, you can save the result into a variable. In the example below, I called it `resultFromMoveDisks`.

Use the method `System.out.println` to output the results. See below for the syntax

```
// in your main method:
int resultFromMoveDisks = moveDisks(1, "", "", "", ""); // you can replace these with your required values

// print using System.out.println
System.out.println(resultFromMoveDisks);
```

Refer to the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) for a good Java introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method, store the result in a local variable, and then print the local variable.